# Table column fixed width

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

I'm having problems with setting a fixed width for table columns. Have a look at jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Stylock/jJ6DK/

The middle column should be `300px` wide, and the left column should be `80px` wide, but for some reason all three columns are the same width. Anyone knows how to fix that?

Comment: Have you specified width of table? Can you post the code here, cause I can't access the jsFiddle because of some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this css style of your table and it should work:

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jJ6DK/6/

When you set `table-layout: fixed` for you table it will take these algorithms:

- The horizontal layout only depends on the table's width and the width of the columns, not the contents of the cells
- Allows a browser to lay out the table faster than the automatic table layout
- The browser can begin to display the table once the first row has been received

Comment: Okay, I think this is the best answer!

Answer (score 2):

Remove `table-layout: fixed` from `table`:

```
table {
    border: 1px solid #D7E4B9;
    background: #B4CDCD; 
}
```

Fixed code: http://jsfiddle.net/jJ6DK/2/